# Show Toast in Android by sending string from c++ JNI in qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I am trying display a toast on the Java method call from C++ side 
I have managed to call that method and even getting string but Toast is not working I have tried almost everything with context and all

C++ Side

```
JavaVMAttachArgs args = { JNI_VERSION_1_6, NULL, NULL };
vm->AttachCurrentThread( &env, &args );
activityConstructor =  env->GetMethodID(activity, "<init>", "()V");
jobject object = env->NewObject(activity, activityConstructor);

toastID = env->GetMethodID(activity, "toast", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
qDebug() << "Moving";
jstring message1 = env->NewStringUTF("This comes from jni.");

qDebug()<< "Test" << message1;
env->CallVoidMethod(object, toastID, message1);
```

Java Side

```
  public void toast(String message){    

    messageData = message;
Log.d(TAG, message);
new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
    esActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){
            Log.d("Message in UIThread", messageData);
            Toast.makeText(context, messageData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
    }
}.start();
```

}

I am gettin string value in message but this Toast does not show anything

Any idea would be appreciated ..thanks

Comment: are you calling the toast method from the main UI thread?

Comment: no, but I have the context from activity...

Comment: Doesn't matter, you can't modify the UI from any thread other than the  main thread, that's why is not showing, just call the Toast.make... from runOnUIThread or a Handler and it will show...

Comment: hmm...I have changed my toast method in above code...but it is still not working ..can you see any issue in it..

Comment: are you getting the Log message?

Comment: no it is not going inside

Comment: just remove the thread and leave the runonuimethod, you don't need the outer thread if you are already in a worker thread...

Comment: Yes, it started without the thread but was not working so added it ...

Comment: What does this question have to do with [tag:qt]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After analyzing my code deeply, I figured out the issue in my code. Hopefully this answer would be helpful for someone in future.

It was the issue in the JNI call in C++ for java method. I had to call the `DetachCurrentThread()` as in JNI the native thread remains attached to VM and it stays inside native method. Improved correct code is

```
JavaVMAttachArgs args = { JNI_VERSION_1_6, NULL, NULL };
vm->AttachCurrentThread( &env, &args );
activityConstructor =  env->GetMethodID(activity, "<init>", "()V");
jobject object = env->NewObject(activity, activityConstructor);

toastID = env->GetMethodID(activity, "toast", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
qDebug() << "Moving";
jstring message1 = env->NewStringUTF("This comes from jni.");

qDebug()<< "Test" << message1;
env->CallVoidMethod(object, toastID, message1);
vm->DetachCurrentThread();
```