# Android : Need to create Toast object in c++ NDK for Toasting Message

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I am new  to android NDK c++ and i don't know how to create Toast object in NDK c++ for Toasting Message
like:

`Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

i want to perform same task in NDK c++ from native-lib.cpp file.

Comment: have a look at  https://github.com/demuyan/AndroidNDKbook/blob/master/ch02/JniToast/jni/jnitoast.c

Comment: Thank you @MuhannadFakhouri that is exactly what i want.

Comment: You're welcome !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show Toast in Android by sending string from c++ JNI in qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255967/show-toast-in-android-by-sending-string-from-c-jni-in-qt)

Comment: can i do same for SharedPreferences and also if you have any material related NDK  c++ android please give me link

Comment: yes @isaaaaame it is also help me thanks

Comment: if anybody have NDK c++ learning material please send me